# Karate API Tests - Post Request failing but works using Jmeter

Tags: karate

I am trying to implement testing POST request for my APIs using KARATE, but getting 403 - expected csrf token not found.

However, I am able to perform POST Request using Jmeter - Login to the application, perform GET request and get the XSRF Token from GET request RESPONSE HEADERS and pass it in the POST request in Header Manager in Jmeter. That way, I am able to create a new resource using POST. I am not sure why this approach isn't working in Karate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be missing some header. The fastest way you can solve this is by collaborating with someone on the server-side dev team.

Refer to this [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/a2ebfceb74047e3900629f7923828cde00b27625/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/signin/sign-in.feature) in the Karate demos that uses CSRF: